# <beans> to <beans:beans> - element beans must be declared

Tags: spring

In the code below, why do I get "element must be declared" (From IntelliJ) if I change the start / end tags from "beans" to "beans:beans"?

What's the significance of the ":beans"?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<!-- HTTP security configurations -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
    <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/backend/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/todoes/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <remember-me key="mySecondSecretWordThatShouldBeHidden" user-service-ref="userAccountDetailsService" />
</http>

<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<!-- Configure Authentication mechanism -->

<beans:bean name="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="secret" value="myVerySecretWordThatShouldBeSomewhereHidden"/>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userAccountDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have bound the security schema to the default namespace using `xmlns=...`. This means you can use the elements in that namespace directly without qualification, e.g. `<authentication-manager>`.

To use an element defined in another schema you need to bind that schema to another namespace and use that as a prefix. Declaring `xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"` binds the schema identified by the URL to the namespace `beans`. The location of the schema is in the `xsi:schemaLocation`. Example usage `<beans:bean>`. Had you declared the namespace as `xmlns:wibble="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"`, then this would change to `<wibble:bean>`.

You could have used any of them as your default namespace, which one makes sense depends on your config file and the types of bean it will have.